# Wrong table when updating "Belongs To" relationships in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pivot-table, laravel-5.1

Here I'm trying to save  article's category with given id which exists in categories table,I have set the relationships but when trying to save, Laravel tries to insert new row in **articles table** not in the pivot table .
Here is the error:

```
  *Unknown column 'category_id' in 'field list' (SQL: update `articles` set    `category_id` = 1, `updated_at` = 2015-11-16 13:15:32 where `id` = 53)*
```

And these are relations and pivot table

```
class Article extends Model implements SluggableInterface
{ 
   public function category()
   {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
   }
}

class Category extends Model implements SluggableInterface
{
     public function articles()
     {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Article','article_category');
     }
}

      //pivot table
    Schema::create('article_category',function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->integer('article_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

And here is my save function

```
public function store(ArticleRequest $request)
{
    $article=Auth::user()->articles()->create($request ->all());
    $category =Category::find($request ->input('category'));
    $article->category()->associate($category)->save();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your relationship type is many to many relotionship, not one to many.

Your models should be like this:

```
class Article extends Model implements SluggableInterface
{ 
   public function categories()
   {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'article_category');
   }
}

class Category extends Model implements SluggableInterface
{
     public function articles()
     {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Article', 'article_category');
     }
}
```

If you want one to many relationship not need 'article_category' table your migrations should like this:

```
Schema::create('articles',function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->integer('id')->increments();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->text('content');

    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

and models:

```
class Article extends Model implements SluggableInterface
{ 
   public function category()
   {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
   }
}

class Category extends Model implements SluggableInterface
{
     public function articles()
     {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Article');
     }
}
```

Comment: An article belongs to only one category, a category can have many articles, is my logic wrong ?

Comment: Second parameter is foreign key in the one to many relationships. But many to many relations need pivot table name in second parameter

Comment: Thanks, I got it that's why I removed the comment,I will vote up after test.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but it looks to me that the relations should be:

```
articlass Article extends Model implements SluggableInterface
{ 
   public function category()
   {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\ArticleCategory', 'category_id');
   }
}
```

and

```
class Category extends Model implements SluggableInterface
{
     public function articles()
     {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ArticleCategory','article_id');
     }
}
```

so it references to the pivot table

Comment: Calin Blaga,As far as I know the second parameters are the name of pivot tables, but I don't have such tables, I only have one pivot table for these relations and that's " article_category"

Comment: It's the foreign key:   public function hasMany($related, $foreignKey = null, $localKey = null)